# Production grade mapping for holidays in python

Tags: python

I am receiving the list of holidays for different cities in the world. So, it is a giant list, but, it is not very clean where similar holidays are named differently. For example: list below:

```
Day off for Boxing Day
New Year's Day 
New Year 
Day off for Boxing Day
New Year's Day
New Year
Day off for New Year's Day (Day 2)
Christmas Day observed
Boxing Day observed
Christmas Eve
Day After New Year's Day observed
Labor Day observed
Liberation Day observed
Holi
Rememberance day Holiday
```

What will be a simple way to map same holiday together? I am maintaining a hard coded dict but everytime something change on API side things start crashing.

Comment: then how do you want the output to be ?

Comment: You seem to very rarely accept answers. Only once in 22 question, although you did receive more than one quality answer. Hopefully you receive even better answers this time.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to your problem may preprocess the list of parsed holiday names by removing certain "stop" words and then use some similarity measure to identify candidates for equivalence.

For instance you might remove "Day", "off" and "for" from the entries. You can further standardize entries by removing "'s".

Depending on your use case this might already suffice. Alternatively you could compute cosine similarity levenshtein distance or something like this to find further equivalences.

If such a flexible mapping is really necessary, because you have no influence on the consumed APIs, then I strongly recommend to use regression tests to prevent breaking behavior after changing the preprocessing code.